# Do we always have the choice between singular and plural in the following construction?

Tags: grammar

Here are some example sentences:

> We should replace all round steering wheels with **a steering wheel**
>   that's rectangular so we are more alert when driving.
>
> We should replace all round steering wheels with **steering wheels**
>   that's rectangular so we are more alert when driving.

I keep forgetting if it's ok to use a singular in sentences where the object is plural and with the preposition with. I think it's wrong, but I think I saw many occurrences where it's used. I think it's wrong, because it makes the sentences very ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a choice. But your second sentence, given that it uses the plural, is ungrammatical.

It should be:

> We should replace all round steering wheels with steering wheels **that are** rectangular so we are more alert when driving.

---

Nobody would think that if you use the singular you mean that you should replace the millions of existing steering wheels with a *single* steering wheel. That wouldn't make any sense. There is a degree of translation that goes on in our heads when we see the first sentence. There is nothing actually *ungrammatical* about it, and it's also something that's used idiomatically.

Note that it's possible to rephrase the first sentence so that all parts of it are explicitly singular:

> We should replace **every** round steering **wheel** with a steering wheel that's rectangular so we are more alert when driving.